# How do I let my django server print a receipt using my client's printer?

Tags: django, web, printing, epson, receipt

I'm working on a web application that allows users to add items to their cart. What I want to do is to print the items in the cart to a kitchen impact receipt printer on my clients side (I'm using the TM-U220 Receipt Printer). Currently, I am using my own computer to run the server but in the future, I hope I can get it working online so anyone can visit the website.

I can't seem to find any solution on how to do that and if it is possible? I've only recently started Django and I can't seem to find a good solution.

Any tips, help or idea on how to writing data to the printer on the client side from Django server?